# NSString returns empty from a return method

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsstring

I have an unusual issue and I can't figure out why:

I have the following method:

```
 - (NSString*) copyAndReplaceOccurencesForProfileFromString: (NSString*)initialString toString:(NSString*)aString
{

        aString = [NSString stringWithString:initialString];
        DLog(@"PROFILE INITIAL HTML STRING: %@", initialString);

        aString = [aString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//PROFILE_IMAGE//" withString:profileImageForHTML];
        aString = [aString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//PROFILE_NAME//" withString:profileBirthNameString];
        aString = [aString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//PROFILE_BIRTHDATE//" withString:profileDateOfBirthString];
        return aString;
    }
```

which is called like this:

```
    NSString *profileSection = [NSString string];
[self copyAndReplaceOccurencesForProfileFromString:htmlBody_profile toString:profileSection];
DLog(@"PROFILE MODIFIED HTML STRING: %@", profileSection);
```

but the "profileSection" string returns empty.

I must point out that "aString" has values in it before calling return on it.

Any idea why is this happening ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** :  Take a look

```
   NSString *profileSection = [NSString string]; //reference created
```

Again in when profileSection passed in method as aString:

```
   aString = [NSString stringWithString:initialString]; //new reference created
```

Now profileSection can never hold string manipulated as reference differs.

---

Make your function return a new NSString.

```
- (NSString*) copyAndReplaceOccurencesForProfileFromString: (NSString*)initialString
{
        NSString *aString = [NSString stringWithString:initialString];
        DLog(@"PROFILE INITIAL HTML STRING: %@", initialString);

        aString = [aString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//PROFILE_IMAGE//" withString:profileImageForHTML];
        aString = [aString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//PROFILE_NAME//" withString:profileBirthNameString];
        aString = [aString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//PROFILE_BIRTHDATE//" withString:profileDateOfBirthString];
        return aString;
}
```

Now use like:

```
NSString *profileSection = [self copyAndReplaceOccurencesForProfileFromString:htmlBody_profile];
DLog(@"PROFILE MODIFIED HTML STRING: %@", profileSection);
```

Comment: Thank you! It works :) ! Would you please explain what was flawed in my concept ?

Comment: I think the first line should be `NSString *aString = [NSString stringWithString:initialString];` or something similar, should it not?

Comment: yes u r right it should work as provide autoreference string with string added in it

Comment: how u understood what was your mistake in this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstand how `return` works. It does not manipulate the values of arguments passed from the caller, rather it determines the value that the method call evaluates to after it finishes. So say you had a method `-(id)someMethod`, and then called it like this:

`id myValue = [self someMethod];`

Inside `someMethod`, there is a return statement - whatever is to the right of the `return` is what will be assigned to `myValue` in the calling method or function.

To apply this to your situation, change your method like:

```
 - (NSString*) replaceOccurencesOfProfileInString:(NSString *)initialString
{

        NSString *aString = initialString;

        DLog(@"PROFILE INITIAL HTML STRING: %@", initialString);
        NSData *profileImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(profileImage);
        NSString *profileImageDataString = [profileImageData base64EncodedStringSingleLine];
        NSString *profileImageForHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<p><b><img src='data:image/png;base64,%@' width='%f' height='%f'></b></p>", profileImageDataString, profileImage.size.width, profileImage.size.height];

        aString = [aString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//PROFILE_IMAGE//" withString:profileImageForHTML];
        aString = [aString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//PROFILE_NAME//" withString:profileBirthNameString];
        aString = [aString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"//PROFILE_BIRTHDATE//" withString:profileDateOfBirthString];
        return aString;
    }
```

Then change your calling code to:

```
NSString *profileSection = [self replaceOccurencesOfProfileInString: htmlBody_profile];
```

Now, you have created a new `NSString` instance and are returning it to the caller, where it is assigned to the `profileSection` variable.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you ! Now I understand but it's odd to me because I've used the same technique with NSMutableArray argument and it worked...

Comment: @codeFi Yes that's because we are passing *pointers* to objects as these arguments. So when you send a message to an `NSMutableArray` instance, you are sending that message to the same instance that's in the caller's context. But, when you change the value of a pointer to an object, like you did here, that is not reflected in the callers context, as the argument is a copy of the pointer. If you really need to change a pointer that also needs to an argument, you must pass a pointer to the pointer as the argument and go from there.

Comment: @codeFi you're welcome, learning lots of details about the language and how it works can be very enriching to the code you write, I highly recommend it!