# Somehow NSUserdefaults save does not work

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In `class 1` i save a `int` converted to a `string`, in `class 2` I try to load this string for some reason it does not work, when I write the string which I get out of `loadString` to a text box in `class 2` the text box stays empty.
When i do the same thing in `class 1` the text box becomes "1".

class 1.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
countForString = 1;
saveString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%i", countForString];
[self SaveTextBox:saveString :@"Number"];
}

-(void)SaveTextBox:(NSString*)string :(NSString*)stringsave
{
NSString *savestring = string;
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:savestring forKey:stringsave];
[defaults synchronize];
}
```

class 2.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self loadString:@"Number":teamString];
tbTeamPlayer.text = teamString;
}

-(void)loadString:(NSString *)location:(NSString *)saveInString
{
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *loadstring = [defaults objectForKey:location];
saveInString = loadstring;
}
```

Comment: [Objective-C naming conventions](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000082.php) please read that and apply it to your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`loadString:location:` doesn't change the value of `saveInString`, all it does is overwrite the local variable. You need to return the string and set that value, e.g.

```
tbTeamPlayer.text = [self loadString:someLocation];
```

and change loadString to do:

```
- (NSString *)loadString:(NSString *)location
{
    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:location];
}
```

Comment: I do not yet completely understand it but this works thanks a lot.

Comment: the string saveInString that you were trying to modify inside the loadString: method is not the same string that you passed in, it is a local copy created just for that method. So you can modifiy it, but those changes will not be reflected in the original string. The best way to handle this is to return a string and overwrite the original one

Answer (score 1):

You really need to work on naming variables, and use naming of parameters. It's one of the best features in ObjC.

From what I understand, your problem is that you think that `saveInString = loadstring;` returns something. It does not. The pointer of the variable is copied when the method gets called.

For returning values, use the return value.

I strongly suggest to start with a good book on Objective C, as this code has really big problems with regard to the language.

Answer (score 0):

In your loadString method **new reference** of **saveInString** is created. So it **cannot reflect to any new modification to original reference**.

Refer [nsstring-returns-empty-from-a-return-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636127/nsstring-returns-empty-from-a-return-method/12636326#12636326) link.